# Join a columns count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot, subquery

I have 2 tables : urls and links.

```
urls
- urls.url

links
- links.source
- links.destination
```

I'm trying to select all the urls and add count of incoming and outgoing URLs, result should be :

```
URL; Count Incoming links; Count Outgoing links
```

I have tried the following to get the incoming URLs which sadly isn't valid SQL, and at this point I don't know how to look for the solution to this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM urls JOIN COUNT(links.source) ON urls.url = links.source
```

Comment: Please provide ample data and desired results.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries:

```
select u.url,
    (select count(*) from links l where l.source      = u.url) as incoming_links,
    (select count(*) from links l where l.destination = u.url) as outgoing_links
from urls u
```

Alternatively, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select u.url,
    sum(case when u.url = l.source      then 1 else 0 end) as incoming_links,
    sum(case when u.url = l.destination then 1 else 0 end) as outgoing_links 
from urls u
left join links l on u.url in (l.source, l.destination)
group by u.url
```

Depending on your database, there might be a neater way to express the conditional sum. For example, in MySQL:

```
sum(u.url = l.source) as incoming_links
```

Or in Postgres:

```
count(*) filter(where u.url = l.source) as incoming_links
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . One method is correlated subqueries:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*) from links l where l.source = u.url) as outgoing,
       (select count(*) from links l where l.destination = u.url) as incoming
from urls u;
```

If you only wanted the urls in `links`, you could unpivot and aggregate:

```
select url, sum(outgoing), sum(incoming)
from ((select source as url, 1 as outgoing, 0 as incoming
       from links
      ) union all
      (select destination as url, 0 as outgoing, 1 as incoming
       from links
      )
     ) oi
group by url;
```